# Can AWS security groups on one AWS account reference security groups in another?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services

For example, I have a main company AWS account one with security group-xxxxx.  Now I have my personal aws with security group-yyyyy.  The accounts are not related at all.  Can I add accept group-yyyyy into the group-xxxxx thereby allowing my personal instances to access the companies instances?

Answer (score 54):

You can use the web UI to add

`other-aws-account-id/account-security-group-id`

e.g.

`951413000000/sg-deadbeef` as the source

Comment: Though the question was asked over a year ago, this should be marked as the proper answer.

Comment: Per @marc-kubischta: "If the security group you want to reference is in another region, you are out of luck. A possible workaround in this case is to set up a proxy using an EIP in the other region and account, and add that proxy's EIP to the security group you are creating." http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5693066

Comment: This is not possible if the security group is within a VPC.

Comment: It appears that @LeighMcCulloch is right.  I tried this and got the following error message: Could not update your security group rules (No changes were made): Groups belonging to other users may not be granted permissions to VPC security groups.

Comment: You cannot reference the security group of a peer VPC that's in a different region. Instead, use the CIDR block of the peer VPC.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/vpc-peering-security-groups.html

Answer (score 16):

For people looking for a solution for this question now, it is possible for security groups to be referenced from cross accounts if their vpc is peered. ! 
Its a new feature from aws ! Cheers

[Link to article](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/03/announcing-support-for-security-group-references-in-a-peered-vpc/)

Comment: A cross-account security group can be referenced, but the reference doesn't appear to matter. I just created a rule to allow all access from an SG in one acct to one in another but instances using those groups can't talk to each other!

Comment: Are the VPC's  peered?

Comment: Hi @p-joel-nishanth-reddy, yes, they are VPC peered.

Comment: Generally, each VPC itself has SG associated with it , please check that first. Also when you associate a SG from another account the rule in the Security shows up in a format something like this "<sg-id>/account-id"

Answer (score 3):

I know this is quite old, but I found an even older [AWS Developer Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=222413) topic which discusses this and it seems possible with the EC2 API tools by using the **ec2-authorize** command (e.g., `ec2-authorize your-account-security-group-id -P tcp -p 10050 -u other-aws-account-id -o other-account-security-group-id`). I've not yet tested it, but I will and then post my results here.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with Security Groups in VPC's and since you can't make Security Groups that aren't in VPC's anymore (at least I can't see how) I don't believe this is possible anymore.

You have to look at VPC peering connections but thats way over my head.